# Separating Data, Query and Index services in Couchbase 4.0

Tags: couchbase

I am migrating from CB3.0 to CB4.0.
In the documentation it is stated that for MDS advantages and for best performance, Query and Index Services should be separated from the Data Service.
I have my data nodes ready and now i would like to add a new node that will run Index Service only and another one that will run Query Service only.

When trying to add a new node, the only possibilities i got are creating a Data node or creating a data-query-index node (all 3 services).
Why can't i add a these nodes as i desire? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multidimentional Scaling is not available in Community edition (Enterprise edition includes it)